# Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug() not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, firephp

I have Firefox 3.6.15, Firebug and FirePHP addons installed, console enabled. I am using Zend 1.11. The following code doesn't show anything in the firebug console.

```
<?php
    require_once('Zend/Log.php');
    require_once('Zend/Log/Writer/Firebug.php');

    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

    $logger->info('info message');
    $logger->warn('warning message');
    $logger->err('error message');
?>
```

I tried with the FirePHP core library and this works -

```
<?php
     require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
     ob_start();

     $firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true); 
     $var = array('i'=>10, 'j'=>20);

     $firephp->log($var, 'Iterators');
?>
```

Would like to get the Zend thing working. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with place

```
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
$channel = Zend_Wildfire_Channel_HttpHeaders::getInstance();
$channel->setRequest($request);
$channel->setResponse($response);
//buffering
ob_start();
```

before logger message.

also after

```
// flushing
$channel->flush();
$response->sendHeaders();
```

Comment: Worked for me too, there isn't any shorter version?

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually the main difference between the 2 fragments of code is that in the FirePHP code you're turning on output buffering (with the `obstart();` call) and in the Zend Framework code fragment you don't. The easiest way to get it to work with Zend is probably to set the `output_buffering` flag in php.ini to On (you can do that in your virtual host definition or htaccess when using apache if you don't want to set it globally).

I just use this in my Bootstrap :

```
protected function _initLogger()
{
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}
```

And then use `Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log(...);` and it works with output_buffering set to on (FF 3.6.15, Firebug 1.6.2, FirePHP 0.5.0).

Comment: this solution does not work unfortunately, I have the latest versions of FF, FBug and FPHP, while the "long" one works

Comment: Works like a charm! FF 14.0.1, FB 1.10.2, FPHP 0.7.1